# Unable to Deploy App on Google App Engine Launcher for Windows 7

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm having a weird problem deploying my Hello World app using the Google App Engine Launcher for Windows 7

Was able to the run it on `http://localhost:8080/` but the problem is:
1. Whenever clicking the "deploy" button, the popup box is small and can't be resized. I can't view the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons 
2. I'm unable to successfully deploy the Hello World app on my __.appspot.com 
3. Once I have entered my email and password and clicked on "OK", no deploy (log) screen pops up

I've tried the ffg. already: 
1. Added Path environment variable for Python on my computer 
2. Went to GAE Launcher >> Preferences >> Set Python Path to C:\Python27\pythonw.exe and App Engine SDK to C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine

Thanks,
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a DOS script to deploy your application:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp